# FFMPEG - Combine Image + Audio into Video, but Output is longer than the Audio File?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, node.js

I am trying to combine a static image & an audio into a video.
I want the video to be as long as the audio file.
I am using ffmpeg and am executing it via nodejs:

```
var args = [
    "-loop",
    "1",
    "-i",
    pathToImage,
    "-i",
    pathToAudio,
    "-c:v",
    "libx264",
    "-tune",
    "stillimage",
    "-b:a",
    "96k",
    "-c:a",
    "aac",
    "-pix_fmt",
    "yuv420p",
    "-f",
    "mp4",
    "-shortest",
    destinationPath,
  ]
  var cmd = "ffmpeg"
  var proc = spawn(cmd, args)
```

So the ffmpeg command that's executed should be this:

`-loop 1 -i pathToImage.png -i pathToAudio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -b:a 96k -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 -shortest destinationPath.mp4`

However, this creates a video which is quite a few seconds longer than my audio file, and I do not understand why that is or how to fix it? I have to admit I do not understand all the parameters 100%, so I am wondering if someone could maybe help me out here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804507/

Answer (score 2):

I don't completely understand this issue myself (something about buffering data apparently), but the [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800185/my-ffmpeg-output-always-add-extra-30s-of-silence-at-the-end/55804507#55804507) provided in the comments offers a brief explanation.

Based on the answers provided there, I solved this in my own experimentation by combining the example in [Gyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804507/3395469) with a sufficiently high input framerate hinted at in [Debrune e brune's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62401005/3395469) answer. With your example above, this resulted in:

`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 10 -i pathToImage.png -i pathToAudio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 96k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M destinationPath.mp4`

In this case, anything lower then `-framerate 10` resulted in a file that was anywhere from 1-4 seconds too long. However, with the given settings, the resulting `.mp4` was exactly the length of the original audio file.

For what it's worth, boosting the framerate higher (in this case) added a small amount of size to the file but otherwise didn't seem to have an effect on length.